# Change formatDate in datepicker of material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datepicker, material-ui

i using material-ui datepicker component with redux form. It looks amazing by i have a little issue here. When i change the date it appears in my input field as yyyy-mm-dd. I want to change it so as to appear as dd-mm-yyyy. The datepicker has a property called formatDate which takes a function as an input.
So i wrote:

```
<Field
      name="dateFrom"
      component={DatePicker}
      hintText="Ημερομηνία από"
      autoOk
      formatDate={() => moment().format(DD-MM-YYYY)}
    />
```

but it does not seem to work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: try this `formatDate={(date) => moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}`.

Comment: Nice!! Thank you! Make it an asnwer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per **[DOC](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker)**:

> **formatDate**  ====> **function**  ====>     This function is called to format
>   the date displayed in the input field, and should return a string.
>
> **Signature**: function(date: object) => any date: Date object to be
>   formatted. returns (any): The formatted date.

---

Receive the selected date as an argument of formatDate function, change the format of the date and return the formatter value as a string.

Another change is:

```
format(DD-MM-YYYY)
```

`DD-MM-YYYY` should be a string like this:

```
format('DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Write it like this:

```
<Field
      name="dateFrom"
      component={DatePicker}
      hintText="Ημερομηνία από"
      autoOk
      formatDate={(date) => moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}
/>
```